# Possibility of having more than one handler in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, python-2.7, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I was wondering if I can have two handlers for one Lambda because for one of my intents which is to get data from local DB and have the data as speech_output, it has to be under the "main handler" as it won't work if it was structure like this one:

```
elif intent_name == "AMAZON.HelpIntent":
    return get_welcome_response()
```

Comment: Simple answer: no, you can have only one handler per lambda. Can you give more info? I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I made two separate lambda functions just to see if they were working correctly. one connected RDS to Lambda, and the other, Lambda to Alexa. Both are working fine separately with their own handlers. My overall plan is RDS-Lambda-Alexa. The main handler should handle the rds part and the lambda to Alexa(speech part). so for the Alexa, I used intent. Currently under the main handler are conditions on sessions like: if event['session']['new']:
        on_session_started({'requestId': event['request']['requestId']},
                           event['session'])  @blueCat

Comment: If I try to add the DB connection part under the main handler, Alexa gives me the response " There was a problem with the requested skills response". @blueCat

Comment: You seem to be asking one thing, while trying to do somethig different.  There is only one *handler* because the *handler* is the first thing that is always invoked... but there's nothing preventing you from using other javascript functions... and `return get_welcome_response()` seems suspiciously incomplete... why are no arguments being passed to the function call?  What is the error shown in the Lambda logs when your code is structured this way?  Also, did you `'use strict';`?

Comment: Sorry, I just started learning how to code 2 weeks ago. for the return get_welcome_response(), it is part of Alexa template for the color picker skill. What I want is just to be able to call the 'method' of getting the data when the intent is called. I get this error: global name 'event' is not defined: NameError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/app.py", line 102, in handler
return on_intent(event['request'], event['session'])
File "/var/task/app.py", line 59, in on_intent
return handler(event, context)
NameError: global name 'event' is not defined @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: Disregard my question about `'use strict';`. I was thinking Javascript.  But this is exactly the kind of error I had in mind.  Though I don't like working with python, and am not particularly familiar with it, it seems like the issue is that the `event` is not in scope in this function, because you need to pass it as an argument.  That's about all I can suggest, and I'm sure it's incomplete, but hopefully someone can come along and make more helpful suggestions, if that doesn't get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you @Michael-sqlbot . I was able to successfully pass it as an argument and is now working correctly. Also had something to do with the structure itself